# Predictions with h2o.randomForest saved model

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I've trained a random forest model in Rstudio, using h2o library, and then i saved it as .rda file, now i would like to score other data using the model buildt. 
So i loaded the model i've turned the new dataset in a H2OFrame and i try to get score using `predict( model, new_data)` function.
What i get is the following error message:

```
    ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/4/Predictions/models/DRF_model_R_1468754145815_1/frames/file1840210c1889_sid_9b90_2)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException: Object 'DRF_model_R_1468754145815_1' not found in function: predict for argument: model"
 [2] "    water.api.ModelMetricsHandler.predict2(ModelMetricsHandler.java:239)"                                                                 
 [3] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                                          
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                                                        
 [5] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                                                
 [6] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"                                                                                     
 [7] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:62)"                                                                                            
 [8] "    water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:655)"                                                                               
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:596)"                                                                                
[10] "    water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:745)"                                                                    
[11] "    water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doPost(JettyHTTPD.java:681)"                                                                       
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                                                         
[13] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                                                         
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                                               
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                                                           
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)"                                                        
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)"                                                          
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)"                                                    
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                                                   
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                                                            
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)"                                                     
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                                                    
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                                                        
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                                                
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                                      
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                                              
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"                                       
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"                                        
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)"                                      
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)"                      
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)"                                                                     
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)"                                                                
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                                               
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"                                         
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                                                     
[36] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                                      
[37] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"                                                                                                

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Object 'DRF_model_R_1468754145815_1' not found in function: predict for argument: model
```

I'm new to H2O.. Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save it as an rda file, from inside R. The model exists on the H2O cluster, and you must use `h2o.saveModel()` to save it. And then `h2o.loadModel()` to load it again.  See `?h2o.saveModel` and `?h2o.loadModel`.

BTW, note the asymmetry between the functions: you give a directory to saveModel, and you give a filename to loadModel.  (The filename will be the model ID.)

Comment: ok thanks! but this means that i have to re-run the model to save it? or i can load tho old model and then save it using `h2o.loadModel()`? (last time the model training took 17h)

Comment: @FrancescoDalPont If you didn't use h2o.saveModel() you cannot load it, and will need to re-make it. Sorry! If the model is taking that long to train, take a look at checkpoints: you can make, say, the first 50 trees, then save that model, but also carry on learning. And repeat this every 50 trees (or every hour - however many trees you make in one hour). Also, once the model is good enough for you, you just stop.